# Html.ActionLink not rendering correctly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I try to render an actionlink in razor, it comes out oddly.

For instance, when I do the following:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Sites", new {itm.Id}, null)
```

On screen, the link I get looks like:

```
Edit (/Sites/Edit/1)
```

In the HTML, it only looks like this:

```
<a href="/Sites/Edit/1">Edit</a>
```

This is like a bad dream. I can't figure out where this crap is coming from. It also does it in Firefox (I normally use Chrome). Interestingly enough, you can't select the text that is showing up. I've never seen this issue before and that text isn't even in the page, except as the url path.

Comment: Do you use any browser plugins or exotic js libraries or jquery plugins? Or some asp.net mvc tools: like Glimpse, MvcProfiler etc.?

Comment: I tried disabling all extensions in the browser. It's still doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this was nice and daft of me. I'm using BluePrint.css on these pages. For some reason, the print version of the blueprint stylesheet was getting output to the page. This prints the hyperlink out by the text like so:
    a:link:after, a:visited:after {content:" (" attr(href) ")";font-size:90%;}

I didn't even know you could do this with css. Thanks to everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Sites", new { @id=itm.Id }, null)
```

Comment: @WillGant: Clear the browser cache ? Did you override the ActionLink helper method somewhere ?

Comment: I tried clearing it, still no luck. I haven't overridden ActionLink. What strikes me about this is the fact that the text isn't in the HTML document that the server sends down. Makes me wonder if there is some javascript or something messing me up.

Comment: @WillGant based on the symptoms my bet is also on some client side javascript code messing up your links. Check with the browser's developer tools which script are loaded maybe you will see some clues...